# Display table with dynamic columns based on date

Tags: java, javafx

It seems the recommended way to populate a `TreeTableView` in Javafx is to create a class that extends `RecursiveTreeObject`, predetermine the column headers, and fill it up via cell value factory. Here's my problem. My Data Structure:

```
public class Problem extends RecursiveTreeObject<Problem> {

  private StringProperty date;
  private StringProperty name;
//getter/setter/constructor

}
```

For example, there are 100 `Problem`s (a `java.util.List`, basically) and they all revolve around 5 (may vary) `dates`. And so I want to group them by date:

```
25-Apr | 26-Apr | 27-Apr | 28-Apr | 29-Apr
Dave     Thomas   Lee      Frank    Riley
John              Albert   Ross     Bob
```

I've been stuck on this for a few hours already. For my TreeTableView, I'm using `JFoenix`, so i'm using the `JFXTreeTableView` (If it helps)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what you are after.

Comment: `TreeTableView` supports grouping rows, not columns. (You can use nested columns though, but you cannot extend those). The desirec output you posted in your question does not indicate any reason for using `TreeTableView` at all. It seems like a `TableView` would be a better choice. Please explain why a `TreeTableView` is necessary.

Comment: I did something similar using a `TableView` a while back. I created the headers using a List of Date and I just used a List of List to insert the data.